# Combination of totally opposite grep options

Tags: grep, recursive

I did: `grep -r -H -L  txt ~`

And `grep -r -l -L txt ~`

Does it lists all the files? Because I am getting a really long output.

Comment: it always searches within FILES. **Listing** directories does not relate to `grep` at all

Comment: I am sorry, I meant listing the files (-H enables grep to list the files as well). I will update the question.

Comment: `-L
--files-without-match

    - Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which no output would normally have been printed. The scanning of each file stops on the first match.
`

Comment: Okay. Probably my combination is very useless and that is why it is giving unexpected output.

Comment: @Fox No no. I am just trying to use -l and -L together. I am getting vague output. So that's what happens probably when we use incompatible options together.

Comment: Yeah I did and it is matching a lot of things. Can't tell if it is really matching everything or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your two commands are exactly the same...they both recurse through your home directory and list files that don't contain the pattern 'txt'.

To prove they have the same output you can do

```
diff <(grep -r -H -L txt ~) <(grep -r -l -L txt ~)
```

Breaking it down a bit...

```
grep -r -H -L
```

is the same as

```
grep -r -L
```

`-H` (print filenames) is implied for any `grep` call that involves more than one file. That's what `-L` does since it lists all files that don't match the specified pattern.

Next...

```
grep -r -l -L
```

is the same as

```
grep -r -L
```

This is simply due to the fact that `-l` and `-L` are conflicting options and in such cases the last flag to appear overrides any previous conflicting flag(s). (Thanks to [@don_crissti](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22142/don-crissti) for pointing this out.)

So you in effect have `grep -r -L` and `grep -r -L`.

Comment: Regarding your statement _"`grep -r -l -L` is the same as `grep -r -L`"_ ... That is true, but not because _"`-l` is implied for any `grep` etc..."_, it is true because of the _"last option"_ rule, that is, if you switch `-l` and `-L` then the statement becomes  _"`grep -r -L -l` is the same as `grep -r -l`"_. IOW, when conflicting options are used, the last one cancels out the others.

Comment: @don_crissti Oh, indeed. I convinced myself it was redundant through my testing but must have fat-fingered something along the way. I will update my answer. Thanks for the correction.